# Como chamar uma função dentro do método setTimeOut() passando parâmetros?

Tags: javascript

Por exemplo, abaixo tenho dois botões que quando clicados exibem conteúdos diferentes:

```js
let btn1 = document.querySelector("#btn1");
let btn2 = document.querySelector("#btn2");

btn1.onclick = () => {
    console.log("BOTÃO 1");
};

btn2.onclick = () => {
    console.log("BOTÃO 2");
};
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Click 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Click 2</button>
```

Mas, se eu quiser chamar o método `log()` após alguns segundos com o método `setTimeout()` passando parâmetros na função a ser chamada no método `setTimeout()`, isso não vai funcionar:

```js
let btn1 = document.querySelector("#btn1");
let btn2 = document.querySelector("#btn2");

btn1.onclick = () => {
    setTimeout(msg("BOTÃO 1"), 1000);
};

btn2.onclick = () => {
    setTimeout(msg("BOTÃO 2"), 1000);
};

function msg(txt) {
    console.log(txt);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Click 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Click 2</button>
```

Isso porque estou chamando a função `msg()` imediatamente, pois informei os parênteses. Como eu posso passar parâmetros para função a ser chamada no método `setTimeout()`?

Answer (score 2):

Exatamente assim, certo?

```
btn1.onclick = () => {
    setTimeout(() => msg("BOTÃO 1"), 1000);
};

btn2.onclick = () => {
    setTimeout(() => msg("BOTÃO 2"), 1000);
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5sgwnk0u/

O `setTimeout` espera uma função de callback, mas a função msg não retorna nada (void) e vai dar erro dizendo que ele espera uma função como callback.

Answer (score 2):

Os dois melhores jeitos de resolver para resolver esta questão são: primeiro criando uma `function` no `setTimeout()` e que essa `function` chama a `function` na qual que você quer que ela exerce, nesse caso a `msg(txt)`.

Já o segundo jeito, na qual é o que mais recomendo e o mais prático é, o `setTimeout` recebe um terceiro parâmetro que é enviado como parâmetro para a `function` ao final do cronômetro. *Porém você terá de criar uma variável ou envia a String como parâmetro no final do `setTimeout` sem problemas.
Exemplo:

```
setTimeout(function, 1000, param1, param2, parametros...);
```

**OPÇÃO 1:**

```js
let btn1 = document.querySelector("#btn1");
let btn2 = document.querySelector("#btn2");

btn1.onclick = () => {
     setTimeout(()=> { msg("BOTÃO 1")}, 1000);
};

btn2.onclick = () => {
    setTimeout(() => { msg("BOTÃO 2")}, 1000);
};

function msg(txt) {
    console.log(txt);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Click 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Click 2</button>
```

**OPÇÃO 2:**

```js
let btn1 = document.querySelector("#btn1");
let btn2 = document.querySelector("#btn2");

btn1.onclick = () => {
    var txt = "BOTÃO 1"
    setTimeout(msg, 1000, txt);
};

btn2.onclick = () => {
    var txt = "BOTÃO 2"
    setTimeout(msg, 1000, txt);
};

function msg(txt) {
    console.log(txt);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Click 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Click 2</button>
```

O que também poderia ser na Opção 2:

```
    btn1.onclick = () => {
    setTimeout(msg, 1000, "BOTÃO 1");
};

btn2.onclick = () => {
    setTimeout(msg, 1000, "BOTÃO 2");
};
```

Espero ter ajudado.